# Except classes and interfaces is there anything else we can write in a java source file?

Tags: java

Except classes and interfaces is there anything else we can write in a java source file? because what ever .java file i have seen will have either class or interface in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from classes, interfaces, and enums, one can write a `package-info.java` which contains the Javadoc comments and annotations for a package.

There is some information regarding `package-info.java` in [Section 7.4.1.1: Package Annotations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.4.1.1) in [The Java Language Specification, Third Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html).

The use of `package-info.java` for package documentation is supported from the Javadoc tool which was shipped in Java 5. The [*What's New in Javadoc 5.0*](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/whatsnew-1.5.0.html) page has an entry on the support for package javadocs.

**Edit:** Added information regarding support for annotations per [Tom Hawtin - tackline](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4725/tom-hawtin-tackline)'s comment.

Answer (score 7):

You can also define [**enums**](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html)

Comment: Yep, its just syntactic sugar and defines a class behind the scenes

Comment: It's all syntactical sugar for a Turing machine. enums are not just classes.

Answer (score 3):

**Nothing!**

According to the JLS a completely blank file is a valid .java file. If you create an empty .java file and compile it, it compiles without error, but doesn't produce a .class file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can also write comments.

Comment: You could write a .java file containing only comments, but I doubt there would me much point using a .java file for something that won't produce any output when you could just use a .txt or .rtf file instead.  That doesn't make your post any less true though!

Comment: @TabbyCool: The point isn't the point. What can you...? Classes, interfaces, enums and comments are all valid answers, as is "nothing". @downvoter: I'd appreciate hearing what you found wrong about my answer.